# Tailwind - Why unprefixed classes for mobile unlike Bootstrap?

Tags: tailwind-css

I recently started using Tailwind CSS and I notice it states (and recommends) to use unprefixed classes for mobile and prefixed classes for larger screens.

This is in contrast to Bootstrap which does the exact opposite.

What are the pros and cons of those mobile-first approach?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting bootstrap 5.0 [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#core-concepts) here

> Mobile first, responsive design is the goal. Bootstrap’s CSS aims to apply the bare minimum of styles to make a layout work at the smallest breakpoint, and then layers on styles to adjust that design for larger devices. This optimizes your CSS, improves rendering time, and provides a great experience for your visitors.

Pretty much all the CSS frameworks use that kind of approach nowadays.
It's always easier to have some *basic* layout for smaller screen resolutions and bigger one adapted w/ some additional styling.

Also, this [website](https://gs.statcounter.com/platform-market-share/desktop-mobile-tablet) is saying that `55.73%` of the web traffic is mobile. Even the `41.46%` of desktop stats do have some small enough resolutions to fit styling considered as "mobile" (like the `1280x720` one).

**TLDR**: make your website look good for the biggest amount of users possible with as less styling as possible, then apply specific CSS for wider resolutions.

[image: desktop screen resolution stats]

I don't know any specific cons of starting by a mobile version but maybe the case in which your webapp is targeted towards an admin kind of layout, who will be used 95% of the time on a desktop.

Comment: I wasn't aware Bootstrap 5 follows mobile-first as well.

Comment: Same goes for Bootstrap 4.0: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints